# Do any English verbs end in -s or -es that are singular?

Tags: english, computational-linguistics

I'm trying to automatically determine if a verb is singular/plural in a program, I cannot think or find on Google any verb that ends in -s or -es before conjugation. Are there any?

Comment: Are you asking for an orthographic "-s"/"-es" or for a phonetic [(ɪ)s]/[(ɪ)z?

Comment: And by "singular" applied to verbs, you mean uninflected or if inflected then only for 1st/2nd/3d person singular or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English verbs ending in -s would be a huge list from -ss alone, but but there are only a few ending in -es that I could find:

- [yes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yes#Verb)
- [res](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/res#Verb)
- [times](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/times#Verb)
- [mules](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mules#Verb)
- [jones](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jones#Verb)
- [snopes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snopes#Verb)
- [Snopes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Snopes#Verb)

All of them, except maybe *to yes*, have limited usage (i.e. they are slang, archaic or just plain rare); your program doesn't really need to take them into account unless you want to be super comprehensive or you plan on using a very specific corpus (for example, add *res* if your text comes from online video-game forums).

Comment: Do you know what a verb is?

Comment: @fdb In fairness, J. Siebeneichler linked to wiktionary entries which specifically refer to word usage as verbs.  Thankfully, I've never heard "yes" used as a verb... an evil fate I hope to avoid if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for an orthographic *-s*/*-es*: there are many examples, e.g. *miss*, *floss*, *fuss*, *kiss*, ...
If it's about a phonetic [(ɪ)s]/[(ɪ)z], there are even moe: e.g. *rise*, *impose*; *sneeze*, *snooze*, *freeze*, ...

Comment: Exactly; and ending with a single -s we have gas, yes, dis, bus.

Comment: Do YOU know what a verb is?

Comment: @fdb I guess I do. What are you trying to say?

Comment: @lemontree I guess fdb is just on a crusade against people confusing "verbs" and "words" like the answer above or the first comment under your answer.

Comment: They're perfectly cromulent verbs.